# Why is mesh still merged to threshold even though mirror modifier is deleted?

Tags: edit-mode, mirror

I deleted the mirror modifier, but the vertical center still stays where it is even in edit mode. How do I make it stay on the body as I move it around? [image]

Comment: make sure symmetry is turned off

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: In *Edit* mode, look (1) either in the *Tool Properties* panel -or- (2) in the tool settings ("toolbar") in the header area. If you cannot see it you need to right-click the viewport header where the menu is and select *Show Tool Settings*. (The header can be at the top or the bottom. It depends on the settings.) Click the *X* to disable the mirror.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ycy.jpg